# NumberFormatter does not respect minimumFractionDigits while using significant digits

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I would like to format and display `Double` with the following rules:

> If there are more than 2 fractional digits, display it as 6
>   significant figures, otherwise just display its original value with a minimum of 2 fractional digits.

In order to format nummbers according to my need, I declared an extension with the following method:

```
extension NSNumber {
    func significantFormattedString(minimum: Int = 2, maximum: Int = 6) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = minimum
        formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = maximum
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

        return formatter.string(from: self) ?? "-"
    }
}
```

And then when testing with the code below:

```
let myNumber = NSNumber(value: 7568.9)
let myString = myNumber.significantFormattedString()
print("\(myString)") // prints "7,568.9"
```

If I comment out the lines specifying `minimumSignificantDigits` and `maximumSignificantDigits`, it works as expected (i.e. displaying a minimum of 2 fraction digits, "7,568.90")

Is there anyway to achieve my desired result, or I can only format the result again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You said "If there are more than 2 fractional digits". A number cannot "have" 2 fractional digits. You can add an infinite number of fractional digits (0) to a number and the value will not change. You are confusing the actual value with a format string.

What you really mean is probably "If 100 times the number is an integer". To do this, you will need an if statement:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
// this checks if the number has two leading fractional digits that are not zero
if (a * pow(10, minimum)).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 {
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = minimum
} else {
    formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = maximum
}
return formatter.string(from: self) ?? "-"
```